# SwiftUI if embedded View

Tags: swift, swiftui

So I have an embedded view in my MainView.Swift

```
VStack(alignment: .leading){
                MediaPlayerView()
            }.frame(height: 250)
```

What I would like to do is tell `MediaPlayerView` that if its frame height is 250 then show X content.

But if no frame height then show Z content.

What is the way to do this?

If full screen mode - I want the play pause button to show.
(Note images don't show play pause button as not yet coded.)[image: Full Screen Mode]

If not in full screen mode I want it to wrap the image and now playing info into a button which can call the MediaPlayerView - and hide the play pause button.
[image: Embedded view.]

Comment: @Asperi Hope the pictures and the added details help. I honestly don't know what would be the best way to do this. That's why I thought I would ask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `GeometryReader` to determine your view's height like this:

```
struct MediaPlayerView: View {
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geo in
            if geo.size.height == 250 {
                Text("Height 250")
            } else {
                Text("Height something else")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

although it would probably be better to pass a parameter to `MediaPlayerView` telling it what you'd like to show.

Something like this could work:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var fullView = false

    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
            MediaPlayerView(showFullView: self.fullView)
        }
        .frame(height: fullView ? 500 : 250)
        .onTapGesture {
            self.fullView.toggle()
        }
    }
}

struct MediaPlayerView: View {
    let showFullView: Bool
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            if showFullView {
                Text("Full view")
            } else {
                Text("logo only")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: the second one looks good, and am sure works, but Ideally I want it to open the sheet

 .sheet(isPresented: self.$showingDetail) {
                                                    MediaPlayerView()
                                                        
                                                }

Currently I know I can wrap it in a button and that works.